# What's wrong with this proof of the 2nd Isomorphism Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm self studying and trying to prove all theorems as I'm going through. Here's my attempt. I'm not certain that this is incorrect, but I took a peek at the proof in the text and it definitely takes a different approach. This seems simpler, so I suspect my approach is incorrect.

Let $G$ be a group with a subgroup $H$ and a normal subgroup $N$. We want to show that $$ H /H\cap N \cong HN / N.$$

Define $\varphi: HN / N \to H / H \cap N $ with the mapping $hN \mapsto h (H\cap N)$.

**Let's first show that $\varphi $ is well defined.**

Suppose $h_1 N = h_2 N$. We want to show that $h_1 (H \cap N) = h_2 (H \cap N)$, or equivalently that $h_1^{-1} h_2 \in H\cap N$. Clearly $h_1^{-1} h_2 \in H$, so it remains to show $h_1^{-1} h_2 \in N$. This follows from $h_1 N = h_2 N$.

**Next, prove that $\varphi$ is surjective.**

$\varphi$ is surjective since for any coset $h H \cap N$ we can take $h N \mapsto h (H\cap N)$.

**Now, we want to show that $\varphi$ is injective.**

Suppose that

$$ h_1 (H\cap N) = \varphi(h_1 N) = \varphi(h_2 N) = h_2 (H\cap N)$$

Then $h_1^{-1}h_2 \in H\cap N \subset N$ so that $h_1 N = h_2 N$.

**Finally, we want to show $ \varphi$ is a homomorphism.**

Consider $h_1 N, h_2 N \in HN / N$. Then

$$ \varphi (h_1 N \: h_2 N) = \varphi(h_1 h_2 N) 
 = h_1 h_2 (H \cap N) \\
= h_1 (H \cap N) \: h_2 (H \cap N) = \varphi (h_1 N) \varphi (h_2 N)$$.

Comment: Your proof looks OK to me.  You can simplify it a bit by noting that you can express an arbitrary element of $HN/N$ as $hN$ rather than writing $hnN$.

Comment: Also, you should probably write $h(H \cap N)$ instead of $hH \cap N$ since the latter could be interpreted as $(hH) \cap N$.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the standard proof more carefully, I realize this is just an unpacked version that doesn't explicitly use the 1st Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Your proof is a straightforward and natural construction of an explicit isomorphism between the two groups. A proof using the 1st isomorphism theorem might instead define $\theta : H \to HN/N$ by $\theta(h) = hN$, then show that this is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $H \cap N$. This allows a quicker proof since, for example, it is obvious that $\theta$ is well-defined.

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate it since I don't have any other form of feedback.